# jQuery Autocomplete Firing to Wrong URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a Jquery UI Autocomplete, defined like so:

```
    $('.postcode-lookup').autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/autocomplete/suburbs',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        term: request.term
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: (event, result) => {
                event.preventDefault()
                //Extra functionality
            },
        })
```

Which works fine on one page in my app. On another page however it flat out does not work - instead of firing the Ajax request to `/autocomplete/suburbs/` , it fires to `?query=...`.

There are 2 other autocompletes on the same page, but I can't see a way they'd be conflicting (if I dump `.data('autocomplete').options.source`, the right function is attached.

I have checked the version of jQuery UI and on both pages, it is the same. Though all other autcompletes on the page where this one is not working do not use `source` and `select` as properties, but use `paramName`, `serviceUrl`, `onSelect`. I can use these properties to get the correct request URL and results with my request, but it causes more errors because I think it expects the server data to be in an exact format and the autocomplete does not function.

I prefer the `source`, `select` format. Is there anything wrong I could be doing that is preventing it from working?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint or `console.log()` in the `source:` function, is it triggered?

Comment: FYI you can just write `source: '/autocomplete/suburbs'`. If the option value is a string, it's treated as a URL.

Comment: I don't see `paramName`, `serviceUrl`, and `onSelect` in the jQuery UI Autocomplete documentation. Are you sure you're not using some other autocomplete widget?